# Build StorageProof for Benchmarks

Tags: storage, cumulus, benchmark

Having some issues in fabricating a realistic `StorageProof` in substrate benchmarks. I can't use `std` and most [examples](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_test_relay_sproof_builder/struct.RelayStateSproofBuilder.html) are using `std` in tests via [sp_state_machine](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_state_machine/index.html).

Currently, I've hard coded the `(root, proof)` by calling the `RelayStateSproofBuilder::default()` in a test and printing the raw bytes. Was wondering if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the test proof builder is std-only. I had the same problem when working with the `pallet-parachain-system` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1709) where i use a hard-coded proof blob as well.
The actual solution would be to make the proof builder no-std, which I started working on but it went stale.

So currently there is no better way AFAIK unless you want to make the proof builder no-std.

Comment: I'd certainly like to help if there's some existing work to build upon.